# Google drive bandwidth per plan

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to find which is the best file hosting services. I see google drive seem the best one, but I wonder that in each plan of Google drive, how much bandwidth they offer?

Comment: google drive is mostly a collaboration tool and not a public file hosting service. one of the drive features includes sharing with public but its not meant for huge views. in fact they just deprecated public folder hosting from drive. you will run into many quotas, some unpublished to prevent abuse.

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Apps, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).